Why is resonance such a widespread phenomenon?
It is easy to mathematically describe the motion of a mass which is attached to a spring and also pushed around by a sinusoidal force. We get a differential equation of the form:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-\omega^2x+A\cos(\omega't)$$
Applying the Fourier transform to this and integrating to obtain the energy, it is possible to see that the energy of the system peaks when $\omega'=\pm\omega$. This is resonance.
But resonance is observed in many situations which are not easy to describe mathematically. If you sing at a wine glass at the right pitch, it might resonate and crack. If an earthquake shakes a building at the right frequency, it might resonate and collapse. If winds shake a bridge at the right frequency, it might resonate and collapse.
Question: Is there a very general mathematical result that explains why resonance is such a widespread phenomenon? I suspect that even if there were such a result, it wouldn't be of much interest to physicists and engineers, for it would only confirm what they already know and consider obvious. This is why I am asking this question on MathOverflow.
Supplementary questions:

What can we assume about the form of the equation? In each of the examples I gave, there is presumably some partial differential equation that describes the system. But I don't think this equation is necessarily linear, and we also cannot assume that energy is conserved, because resonance is observed even in damped systems (e.g. systems with friction).

Wave equation: How can we prove that resonance in a system described by the wave equation $\nabla^2 f=\partial_t^2f$ happens when the driving frequency matches the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2$? What relates resonant frequencies to eigenfrequencies?


Edit (14/9): clarifications / further questions:
For convenience, let us limit our discussion to the wave equation.
Suppose the state of a system (e.g. the air in a closed room) is described by a function $u(\mathbf{x},t)$ (e.g. the air pressure at time $t$ and point $\mathbf{x}$ in the room), which obeys the wave equation:
$$\partial_t^2 u=\nabla^2 u$$
As Michael Engelhardt explains in his answer, the qualitative content of the wave equation is that the system is an ensemble of harmonic oscillators which are each coupled to their nearest neighbours. The restoring force that each oscillator exerts on the surrounding oscillators is (to a good approximation) linear.
Eric Towers explains in a comment that these are empirical truths which cannot be deduced through purely mathematical reasoning. I understand this, and I apologise for not making it completely clear what I was looking for.
Nature give us the premise that the system is described by the wave equation, and also the boundary conditions (e.g. if $u$ is air pressure, then there is no pressure gradient perpendicular to the walls of the room).
The rest of our discussion can proceed along purely mathematical lines.
Normal modes are eigenfunctions of the relevant linear operator (e.g. Laplace operator), and these eigenfunctions form a complete basis for the space of all solutions. This is a purely mathematical fact.
If our system is driven by external forces, the equation that describes it is now:
$$\partial_t^2 u=\nabla^2 u + f(\mathbf{x},t)$$
where $f$ describes the external forces.
I would like to see the following questions answered in mathematical terms.
Questions:
1.Mathematically, how do we describe the 'excitation' of a particular normal mode? What conditions must $f$ satisfy in order for $u$ to be, or approach asymptotically, a normal mode?

Why does resonance happen exactly when the system is in a normal mode? How can the correspondence between "resonance" and "normal mode" be seen mathematically?

Can resonance happen in only some regions of the system? How can this be expressed mathematically? For example, if a driving force is applied to the system in a very localised manner (e.g. a speaker playing a sound in the corner of a big room).



About your follow-up questions - just expand the driving force $f$ into the normal modes of the system. Then the problem decomposes into independent problems for each normal mode that each behave like the single harmonic oscillator you start out with in your post, and for each of them, you can assess whether the resonance condition is satisfied. You can excite any number of modes; if you want just one of them, just make sure that $f$ is such that the resonance condition is satisfied for only one of the modes.

Whether resonance happens only in some regions of the system depends entirely on whether the system supports localized normal modes. It is not determined by localizing $f$. You don't excite regions of space, you excite normal modes. It's a different basis.

To try to summarize everything: The forces acting on a system near equilibrium are approximately linear functions of the involved variables (by Taylor expansion). This gives a linear operator. This linear operator has eigenvalues, and we can express both the forces and every external force in terms of an eigenbasis. This reduces everything to many cases of the problem you discuss in the beginning of your answer. If any eigenvalue is positive the equilibrium is unstable and thus unlikely to be observed in practice, and if they all are negative we get resonance.

Resonant phenomena should occur if the force, projected onto any member of the eigenbasis, integrated in time against the resonant frequency, takes a large value. In the specific system you wrote down the eigenvectors are smoothly distributed in space so any external force that is localized in space will be spread around many different eigenvectors in the eigenbasis, so it will correspond to a small force on each individual harmonic oscillator.

However, if the frequency in time of oscillations in the force matches the resonant frequency of one of the harmonic oscillators, you will eventually get enough resonance, and thus see waves throughout the entire room. Of course, in the real world there is friction, which reduces the effect of resonance and might make the waves throughout the entire room small in pratctice.

Thanks everyone! Being quite new to all this, I find it quite surprising that the eigenvectors (i.e. normal modes) always form a complete basis, such that even the driving force can be expanded in it.

Most systems you see around you are subject to a restoring force (otherwise, they'll go find an equilibrium elsewhere). Most restoring forces are linear as long as you're not too violent with the system (that's just Taylor expansion around the equilibrium). All systems you see couple to external forces (otherwise, how would you ever detect that they're there). So the elements contained in your basic resonance equation are ubiquitous.
The fact that most of the systems you see (glass, building, bridge) are multi-dimensional doesn't change this qualitatively. They all have normal modes, which each behave one-dimensionally.
Wave equations arise in systems that consist of many nearest-neighbor-coupled harmonic oscillators. Such a system, again, can be decomposed into its normal modes, which can each be resonantly excited. The eigenvalues of the Laplacian provide the wavenumbers that are related to the resonant frequencies through the wave speed.

This is a convincing qualitative argument, but I was looking for a mathematification of the relevant notions, and a theorem that has the same qualitative content as what you have written here

Additionally (as I indicated at the end of the original post), I would like to know why resonant frequencies correspond to eigenvalues of a differential operator

Reality has a nasty habit of resisting formalization into a neat theorem that fits into an MO answer. Everything we're saying here is an approximate model of reality, to which the corrections have to be considered case by case. To some extent, you already gave the mathematification (up to the ingredient that coupled harmonic oscillators can be diagonalized), and I answered the remaining question as to why this is the right one. This type of question will often not have a clean formal answer,  because that's not how reality is.

Why does the system enter a normal mode when it is driven at a resonant frequency? To my understanding, the system is in a "normal mode" when it oscillates sinusoidally at the same freqency at every point. This is also known as a "stationary wave". Mathematically, this means that if $f(x,y,z,t)$ is a function describing the state of the system, then $f(x,y,z,t)=A(t)g(x,y,z)$ where $A$ is sinusoidal. I don't have any intuition for what normal modes have to do with resonance.

@semisimpleton - it seems to me you have the ingredients: To solve the wave equation, you need $\nabla^{2} g = -k^2 g$ as well as $A(t)=ae^{i\omega t} $, and to make these fit together, $\omega = |k|$. Now, $A(t)$ satisfies a standard harmonic oscillator equation with $\omega = |k|$. This is without any external force; now you can couple to an external driving force like any other oscillator, and you get resonance around $\omega = |k|$.

@semisimpleton : That restoring forces (just one of the "relevant notions" in this Answer) are approximately linear (for small enough displacements) is a result of Physics, not mathematics.  Physicists can tell us that observed restoring forces have such a property, but that is a consequence of observation and experiment, not some a priori mathematical necessity.  Much of your question is of this shape.  Now, once the Physicists have told us the "relevant notions" of this Answer apply to a system, then eigen-decomposition of the (small displacement) linear behaviour gives normal modes.

@EricTowers I have edited the main post to include more questions and to clarify what I was looking for. The new questions I have added are possible to answer in purely mathematical terms, I believe.

Resonance is so universal because Fourier analysis is so universal, and because physical equations of motion are second-order.
Michael Engelhardt already explained why Taylor expansion around stable minima means that we can describe oscillations as linear, and that multidimensional systems oscillators can be expanded into normal modes, so it suffices to look at one-dimensional ones.
Here I want to address two possible misconceptions the OP may have. The first misconception is that damping is a sign of non-linearity. This is not so, since damped oscillations are described by the linear homogeneous equation
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x+2\gamma\frac{d}{dt}x+\omega^2x = 0
$$
whose solutions decay exponentially like $e^{-\gamma t}$ (there are three cases depending on whether $\gamma>\omega$, $\gamma=\omega$ or $\gamma<\omega$, with the system actually "oscillating" as in repeatedly crossing $x=0$ only in the last case).
The second misconception is that resonance is somehow specific to driving by a sinusoidal force. This is not so, since in the inhomogeneous equation
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x+2\gamma\frac{d}{dt}x+\omega_0^2x = f(t)
$$
we can always Fourier expand $f$ and write the equation in frequency space as
$$
\left(-\omega^2+2i\gamma\omega+\omega_0^2\right)x(\omega) = f(\omega)
$$
Then, as long as $f$ has Fourier components $\omega\approx\omega_0$, the Fourier components $\omega\approx\omega_0$ of $x$ will blow up due to the expression in brackets being almost zero.
The last point about Fourier transforms also explains why resonance frequencies are related to eigenvalues of a differential operator, since they are simply the frequencies under which the system oscillates in the absence of a driving force, and the linear homogeneous equation above can of course be rewritten as
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+2\gamma\frac{d}{dt}\right)x = -\omega^2 x
$$
which is an eigenvalue equation for the operator in brackets.

While your answer is nice, I am quite sure that resonance remains universal in the absence of Fourier analysis, in the absence of humans, and in the absence of life in general. Things will still heat or break if hit with the matching frequency, regardless of the source of energy (stars, planet-shakes, ...).

What makes you think Fourier analysis requires humans? I'm a platonist BTW.

My definition of analysis requires intelligence of some kind. Everything non-alive just "is" or just "does". The planets just exist, the protons just exist, the volcanos just erupt, the supernovas just explode... There is no analysis in the mineral world. Just causes, reactions to causes, and effects. And in the particular case of the Fourier analysis, Fourier was a human. Do you fancy a cat or a camomile finding those formulas? :) (I am not angry or sarcastic, i just don't know how to write it better today)

For me "Fourier analysis" is a theory, not an activity. It consists of relationships between functions and functional spaces, which exist independently of anyone being aware of them or using them to "analyse" anything.

Even as a theory, analysis is a result of intelligence. Do you know any stone doing any analysis o theory? The way I see it, there are natural phenomenons, which can happen to mineral world as well as to the living world, and there are explanations about it (theories, analysis etc.) which try to explain it - for the benefit of some intelligence. Functions themselves were created by humans. Volcanos cannot care less about functions or about the formalization of theories.

The way I see it, a theory, or an analysis, is just a description of something natural, living or mineral. A parallel is "a car" and the "description of a car". While the "description of a car" is usually for free (no money), "the car" itself can be quite expensive. The same with: "electromagnetic wave" and "Fourier analysis of the electromagnetic wave". The first exists naturally, the other one is an explanation / description of the first one - done by some humans (or other intelligent beings).

@virolino Replacing the awkward expression "Things to which Fourier analysis may be applied are universal" with the simpler "Fourier analysis is universal" is a common figure of speech among mathematicians, and is not usually meant to imply any philosophical claims about the relationship of mathematics to human thought.

A model independent way to describe a resonance is through the frequency dependent scattering operator $S(\omega)$. Causality requires that this object is analytic in the upper half of the complex $\omega$-plane. In the lower half it may have poles, say at $\omega=\Omega-i\Gamma$. This gives a resonant response when excited at a frequency within $\Gamma$ of $\Omega$.
Concerning the relation between resonant frequencies and eigenfrequencies: At frequencies near resonance one can expand near the pole,
$$S(\omega)=(H-\omega+i\Gamma)(H-\omega-i\Gamma)^{-1},$$
with $H$ a Hermitian operator (so that $S$ is unitary). The resonant frequency $\Omega$ then corresponds to an eigenvalue (eigenfrequency) of $H$.
The operator $H$ does not need to produce a simple wave equation. For example, this description of resonant scattering applies to nuclear physics, where the resonance is a bound state of strongly interacting elementary particles.

How is this scattering operator defined?

The scatterer is assumed to occupy a compact region in space,  so that one can construct a basis of incoming and outgoing waves far from the scatterer. Outgoing waves are linearly related to incoming waves by the scattering operator. For a discrete basis the operator is a matrix, such that $\psi_n^{\rm out}=\sum_m S_{nm}\psi_m^{\rm in}.$
